# Getting SQL MIN() and MAX() from DBIx::Class::ResultSetColumn in one query

Tags: sql, perl, orm, dbix-class

I want to select the `MIN()` and `MAX()` of a column from a table. But instead of querying the database twice I'd like to solve this in just one query.

I know I could do this

```
my $col = $schema->result_source("Birthday")->get_column("birthdate");
my $min = $col->min();
my $max = $col->max();
```

But it would query the database twice.

The only other solution I found is quite ugly, by messing around with the `select` and `as` attributes to `search()`. For example

```
my $res = $rs->search({}, {
   select => [ {min => "birthdate"}, {max => "birthdate"},
   as     => [qw/minBirthdate maxBirthdate/]
});
say $res->get_column("minBirthdate")->first() . " - " . $res->get_column("maxBirthdate")->first();
```

Which produces this - my wanted SQL

```
SELECT MIN(birthdate), MAX(birthdate) FROM birthdays;
```

Is there any more elegant way to get this done with `DBIx::Class`?

And to make it even cooler, is there a way to respect the inflation/deflation of the column?

Comment: Seems like a complicated way  over there regular DBI of just writing an sql string with place holders.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no other way. The current syntax allows exactly what you want so I'm not sure why you're looking for a different solution. Note that 'columns' instead of 'select' + 'as' is recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [columns](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#columns) as a shortcut to combine *select* and *as* attributes as such:

```
my $res = $rs->search(undef, {
    columns => [
        { minBirthdate => { min => "birthdate" } },
        { maxBirthdate => { max => "birthdate" } },
    ]
});
```

Or, if you prefer more control over the SQL, use string refs, which can help with more complex calculations:

```
 my $res = $rs->search(undef, {
    columns => [
        { minBirthdate => \"MIN(birthdate)" },
        { maxBirthdate => \"MAX(birthdate)" },
    ]
});
```

Now, if you really want to clean it up a bit, I highly recommend [DBIx::Class::Helpers](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-Helpers-2.020001/), which allows you to write it as such:

```
my $minmax = $rs->columns([
    {minBirthdate=>\"MIN(birthdate)"},
    {maxBirthdate=>\"MAX(birthdate)"},
])->hri->single;
say "$minmax->{minBirthdate} - $minmax->{maxBirthdate}";
```